# Console.Clear() is not clearing the console

Tags: c#, console

(IDE: Jetbrains Rider)

I am trying to make a Rock Paper Scissors game.
After the game is over, the program asks if the player wants to
play again.
If the player plays again, it clears the console but that doesn't work.

Then i tested writing a while loop that Clears the console, then writes a number.

I made a extra project where i wrote this in.

```
namespace Test
{
    
    public class Program 
    {
    
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double num = 1;
            while (true)
            {
               Console.Clear();
               Thread.Sleep(100);
               Console.WriteLine();
               num += 1;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The loop is the only thing running.

And the output is:

```
60

71
74

85

93

124
127

162
165
```

Does anyone know why?

I thought the problem was .Net 5.0, because i changed to .Net Framework 4.8, and it worked.

Now i restarted rider, and the problem is coming again.

Comment: That loop, as is it written, is not the problem,  that loop just  runs forever and you shouldn't see anything printed out. The problem must be in different part of the program.

Comment: I assume that it's some issue with the IDE console. If you run the program it in the system terminal, it will probably work.

Comment: Many different .NET versions work as expected for me on Rider 2021.1.1.

Comment: The loop is the only thing running in the program. Sorry for not saying it in the problem.

Comment: @DasDarkLord Could you show the whole program?

Comment: I updated the code.

Comment: It works [here](https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/ClumsyShorttermVirtualmachines#main.cs), but I had to rearrange your code to make it work.  The code you've provided just produces a blank screen.

Comment: The problem was Rider. As @ChiefTwoPencils said, if i ran the program on the system terminal, it would work. I tried it and it did nothing (Blank screen). I tried running it on the system terminal again, and now it worked.

Comment: Your code never writes anything to the console except a blank line, so I don't see how the claimed output is possible.

Comment: The IDE is the problem. Console.Clear() doesn't clear the console on my settings. I am trying to fix it now.

Comment: Same problem here using Rider.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use VS 2019 and .Net 5.0, There is no problem with Console.Clear()
Maybe there is an IDE issue. Jetbrains Rider is "buggy" sometimes.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double num = 1;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(num);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            num += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that `Console.Clear()` is not working as expected with Rider IDE 2021.2. See issue logged [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-66804#focus=Comments-27-5258548.0-0).
Updating to Rider 2021.3 EAP 3 apparently solves this problem

As a work around **launch the console window externally**. This works for me in Rider:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This seems to be problem also in 2023.3.3 and your solution worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Try to check whether the environment allowing it of not and then try instead of Console.Clear() to console.clear()

Comment: That didn't fix my problem. But thanks for answering!